# Why does FFmpeg's xfade filter need the timebase and frame rate to match?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding, video-editing

As I discovered [not long ago](https://superuser.com/a/1643589/323079), and recently had to rediscover after trying to use it again, `xfade` - the crossfade filter that FFmpeg introduced in 2019 - requires that both inputs have a matching timebase (TBN) and frame rate (FPS).

This is "resolved" by explicitly making them the same, by adding `SETTB` and a hardcoded FPS to both streams (there doesn't seem to be a constant equivalent to `AVTB` for FPS) prior to using `xfade`:

```
-filter_complex \
[0:v]settb=AVTB,fps=29[v0];
[1:v]settb=AVTB,fps=29[v1];
[v0][v1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=$fadeduration:offset=$fadetime,format=yuv420p[faded];
```

However, I'm confused as to why is this necessary in the first place. The `concat` filter works similarly in that requires all its inputs to have matching parameters, but this makes sense because the whole point of `concat` is to avoid re-encoding. If the `xfade` filter is (presumably) re-encoding anyway, why do the timebase and frame rate still need to match?

Is there a reason the devs decided to enforce these limitations for the filter when they don't seem to be technically necessary?

Comment: I think the situations are the same: both filters append a stream after another. (reencoding has nothing to do with this really). The primary issue is that a stream cannot have multiple timebases AFAIK. Also, you typically don't want cfr video to become vfr without your explicit instruction. Finally, it keeps the algorithm cleaner with matched timing.

Comment: @kesh Interesting, I've always assumed that was to do with concat not being able to re-encode. *Also, you typically don't want cfr video to become vfr without your explicit instruction.* Would that not also be true the other way around? You wouldn't want your VFR video to become CFR, but you're forced to do this - and do the same to the timebase - when using `xfade`.

Comment: I'd say that `xfade` and `concat` are cfr tools. I can certainly see someone can modify it to work with vfr inputs, but that'll complicate the computation (unnecessarily for 99%+ of the use cases) and subjectivity (which stream's timestamps to honor). Ultimately, if you need them to work with vfr stream, you can modify it and submit the patch to see if other devs buy into it.

Comment: The timebase match is not necessary. ffmpeg can compare timebases, and it can recompute to a new timebase. The frame rate match and the CFR requirement is mainly for aesthetics. With unmatched framerates or uneven density then the transition may appear stuttered. Consider that neither overlay nor blend filter have these requirements.

Comment: @Gyan This is another good point that I'd forgotten. The current crossfade solution that I prefer - which I believe you came up with - uses `overlay` to work and it doesn't require anything to match. If the `xfade` filter could be updated to work in the same way, instead showing a warning that the output may appear stuttery (though I haven't ever noticed this with the `overlay` solution) I think this would be an improvement over the current situation. It would also make for a more consistent user experience, as opposed to filters that work in completely different ways when they don't need to.